# Sort subarrays according to their first element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, let's say each object is of a type Grid.

Each Grid object has x and y coordinates,

```
Grid temp = new Grid(3, 5);
// temp.x returns x, temp.y returns y.
```

Now I have a few arrays of Grid

```
Grid[] theArray1 = new Grid[5];
Grid[] theArray2 = new Grid[5];
Grid[] theArray3 = new Grid[5];
```

I fill the arrays up with Grid objects and sort them using Arrays.sort.

I now join the sorted arrays to form theArray with length 5+5+5=15.

I now want to sort theArray by the first element of the "subarrays" (elements 0, 5 and 10 in theArray)

How could I achive this? Also, if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result, that would be nice. But I have to start with the 3 arrays since they are gotten through an iteration of a for-loop.

**EDIT:**

Example: Let's say I sort by X coordinated, smaller first.
I'll make each Grid[] of length 3 instead of 5 for simplicity.

```
Grid[] theArray1 = new Grid[]{new Grid(2, 1), new Grid(4, 1), new Grid(0, 1)};
Grid[] theArray2 = new Grid[]{new Grid(4, 2), new Grid(3, 1), new Grid(7, 1)};
Grid[] theArray3 = new Grid[]{new Grid(1, 7), new Grid(5, 3), new Grid(10, 1)};
```

What I want to end up with is an array/arraylist that, when printed, prints like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= theArray.length-2; i++) {
    StdOut.println(theArray[i] + ", " + theArray[i+1] + ", " + theArray[i+2] + "\n");
}

// Output:

(0, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1) //this is theArray1
(1, 7), (5, 3), (10, 1) //this is theArray3
(3, 1), (4, 2), (7, 1) //this is theArray2
```

First I sort each theArray(1, 2 and 3) so that the element with the lowest x coordinate is first, then second smallest, then largest.

Then I arrange these arrays by the size of the first element of each of them. theArray3 goes before theArray2 because the x coordinate of the first element is 1 but 3 in theArray2

Comment: What do you mean by "sort theArray by the first element of the 'subarrays'"? Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Couldn't you just look at the first element of the sub arrays, make the appropriate comparisons, and then build theArray?  I might not actually understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Grid` implements `Comparable<Grid>`, sort each array and add to 2d-array. Then sort that array of arrays of grids using `Arrays.sort(Grid[][], GridArrayComparator)`, where `GridArrayComparator` looks for example like:

```
class GridArrayComparator implements Comparator<Grid[]> {
   public int compare(Grid[] grids1, Grid[] grids2) {
       if (grids1.length > 0 && grids1.length > 0) {
           return grids1[0].compareTo(grids2[0]);
       } else if (grids1.length > 0) {
           return 1;
       } else if (grids2.length > 0) {
           return -1;
       } else {
           return 0;
       }
   }
}
```

Then copy 2-d array to 1-d array.

Comment: I get the error: GridArrayComparator cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 2d array instead of 3 separate arrays.  Then you could first sort the 2d array to get them in order in relation to each other, then join them.

```
    Grid[][] twoD;

    /* ... */

    // sort each array separately
    for(int i=0; i<twoD.length; i++){
        Arrays.sort(twoD[i], /* COMPARATOR */);
    }

    // sort the arrays based on x coordinate of first element
    Arrays.sort(twoD, new Comparator<Grid[]>() {
        public int compare(Grid[] a, Grid[] b) {
            return Integer.compare(a[0].x, b[0].x);
        }
    });

    /* NOW JOIN THEM */
```

If there are literally only ever 3 arrays though, you could really just check which is smallest, add that first, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit heavyweight, but works. Assuming you have your array merged which has to be sorted(`theArray`), you can create a special *list view* over your array:

```
private static class BlockBasedListView<T> extends AbstractList<T[]> {

    private int blockSize;
    private T[] array;

    public BlockBasedListView(T[] array, int blockSize) {
        this.array = array;
        this.blockSize = blockSize;
    }

    @Override
    public T[] get(int index) {
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, index * blockSize, index * blockSize + blockSize);
    }

    @Override
    public T[] set(int index, T[] element) {
        T[] previousElement = get(index);
        System.arraycopy(element, 0, array, index * blockSize, blockSize);
        return previousElement;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array.length / blockSize;
    }

}
```

This is a simple list implementation of which one element is a block of elements (with size `blockSize`) of your original array. Note that this is a *view* of your array: writes to this list affects the original array.

Then, you create a comparator of a block of `Grid`:

```
private static class CompareByFirstElement implements Comparator<Grid[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Grid[] o1, Grid[] o2) {
        return o1[0].x - o2[0].x;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can sort `theArray` as follows:

```
BlockBasedListView<Grid> blockBasedList = new BlockBasedListView<Grid>(theArray, 5);
Collections.sort(blockBasedList, new CompareByFirstElement());
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to do this, but the the solution above was better fitting to my example. Thanks for putting your time into this.

Answer (score 0):

When you join the sorted arrays you make a new array with size 15. The new array has values which added to it, but has no relation with the subarrays. So, if you apply sort, it would be on the whole array. If you need to sort, you have to use another array variable of size 5, sort that and then write back to main array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Comparable, maybe this helps..

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Grid implements Comparable<Grid> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grid a = new Grid( 2, 15 ); // 3
        Grid b = new Grid( 1, 1 ); // 2
        Grid c = new Grid( 0, -13 ); // 1
        Grid d = new Grid( 4, 0 ); // 4

        Grid gridArray[] = new Grid[] { a, b, c, d };
        System.out.println( "Printing non sorted:" );
        for ( Grid grid : gridArray ) {
            System.out.println( grid.getX() + ", " + grid.getY() );
        }
        System.out.println( "Sorting..." );
        Arrays.sort( gridArray );

        System.out.println( "Printing sorted:" );
        for ( Grid grid : gridArray ) {
            System.out.println( grid.getX() + ", " + grid.getY() );
        }
    }

    private int x, y;

    public Grid(int x, int y) {
        this.setX( x );
        this.setY( y );
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Grid grid) {
        // ascending order
        return this.getX() - grid.getX();
        // descending order
        // return grid.getX()-this.getX();
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}
```

Now Arrays.sort will use natural ordering (Comparable), see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])

This is the output after executing the given main method:

```
Printing non sorted:
2, 15
1, 1
0, -13
4, 0
Sorting...
Printing sorted:
0, -13
1, 1
2, 15
4, 0
```